# Replace or Update text in XML

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a column with XML data.

```
SELECT roll_id, EXTRACT (xml_data, '/root/xmldata/empid') AS empid
  FROM employee_data
 WHERE roll_id IN (1, 2)
```

Result:

```
roll_id      empid  
     1       <empid>A11</empid>  
     2       <empid/>
```

If I run below update query, it updates only roll_id 1. It doesn't impact roll_id 2. Can anyone suggest on how I can update roll_id 2 ? Should I run a replace for roll_id ?

```
UPDATE employee_data
   SET xml_data =
          UPDATEXML (xml_data
                    ,'/root/xmldata/empid/text()'
                    ,'111')
 WHERE     roll_id IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove text() from xpath.

`.../empid/text()` - you are looking for empid with text node.
.../empid` - you are looking for empid.

```
UPDATE employee_data
   SET xml_data =
          UPDATEXML (xml_data
                    ,'/root/xmldata/empid'
                    ,'111')
 WHERE     roll_id IN (1,2)
```

Note. `updatexml` and other xml modification method are deprecated from oracle 11.2. You should to use.

```
update employee_data
   set xml_data   = xmlquery('copy $d := .  
       modify (  
         for $i in $d/root/xmldata/empid
         return (          
           replace value of node $i with "111"  
         )  
       )  
       return $d' passing xml_data returning content) where  roll_id IN (1,2)
```

Comment: How can I pass value of 111 in a parameter ? For example, I want to provide P_ID as input parameter in place of 111 in code.  : return (          
           replace value of node $i with "{@P_ID}"  
         )

Comment: I tried the first method, it just clears whole empid node. Is there a way I can pass 111 as a parameter as I will be passing values through a stored procedure.

Comment: `passing xml_doc as "doc" , 111 as "id"   ` and replace `'copy $d := .  ` -> `'copy $d := $doc `,  `replace value of node $i with "111"` ->  `replace value of node $i with $id`